# Removing values with mixed datatypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have the following DataFrame

```
A       B       C
1.0     abc     1.0
abc     1.0     abc
-1.11   abc     abc
```

I have mixed datatypes (`float` and `str`). How can I drop values `<= -1` in `column A`.

I get an error if I do the following because of the mixed datatypes

```
df['A'] = (df['A'] != "abc") & (df['A'] > -1)
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

How can I change my object to make `abc` a `str` and `1.0` a `float` so I can:

```
(df['A'] != "abc") & (df['A'] > -1)

print(df['A'].dtype)
    -> object
```

I would like the expected output

```
df = 

A       B       C
1.0     abc     1.0
abc     1.0     abc
NaN     abc     abc
```

Comment: What do you mean "I get an error"? Please give us a [mcve] that shows us the actual exception traceback and the actual code (and reproducible sample data) that produces it, or we can't debug it.

Comment: As a wild guess, I think you're looking for a short-circuiting operator here, which you can't do "externally" over a series, but worst-case scenario you can always `apply` or `map` something like `lambda x: x != "abc" and x > -1`. Or, maybe more simply, you can filter it in two steps instead of one: first remove the strings, then you have a series of floats so you can remove the too-small floats.

Comment: Also, if your only non-float value is the string `'abc`', do you really want dtype object for that, instead of using dtype `float` and converting that `'abc'` into a `NaN` float value?

Comment: Do you want values <= -1 to be converted to `NaN`?

Comment: I want to keep `abc` in my dataframe but remove any `float < -1.0`

Comment: @Tai ugh sorry I always forget to add my expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least a couple of different approaches to this problem.

#### loc + pd.to_numeric

[`pd.DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) accepts Boolean series, so you can calculate a mask via [`pd.to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) and feed into the `loc` setter.

Note there is no need to specify `df['A'] != 'abc'` because the `mask` series will convert these values to `NaN`.

```
mask = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce') < -1
df.loc[mask, 'A'] = np.nan

print(df)

     A    B    C
0    1  abc    1
1  abc    1  abc
2  NaN  abc  abc
```

#### try / except

See [@Jan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50687964/9209546). This solution is preferable if you *expect* values to be numeric and are only looking for alternative treatment in edge cases.

Comment: Thank you! I then included `df['A'] = df['A'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore', downcast='float')` because when I open the file in excel it stores it as text. Please know if this seems efficient to you.

Comment: @g_altobelli, That seems fine. Note it's not a requirement to set `downcast='float'`, but it should do no harm.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a little function converting the values to numbers:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1.0, 'abc', -1.11], 
    'B': ['abc', 1.0, 'abc'], 
    'C': [1.0, 'abc', 'abc']})

def change(value):
    try:
        v = float(value)
        if v < -1:
            value = np.nan
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return value

df['A'] = df['A'].apply(change)
print(df)
```

This yields

```
     A    B    C
0    1  abc    1
1  abc    1  abc
2  NaN  abc  abc
```

Comment: Also, I see no reason you need to convert to `float`. If it's not possible, it should be caught by `ValueError`.

Comment: This works but why do I have to do `try` and `except`? Why cant I just tell `pandas` to keep `str` and `drop any float < -1.0`?

Comment: @jpp: You'll get a type error if you don't convert it (TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int').

Comment: You can include a tuple of exceptions :)

Answer (score 0):

You need the indices of the rows where your condition is met. You can convert series to numeric, which would turn string into `NaN`, then look for your condition and simply remove the row. Note that we are not saving the series with `NaN` back to the dataframe.

```
ser = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce')
df.loc[df['A']!='abc'].drop(list(ser[ser<=-1].index))
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C
0  1.0  abc 1.0
```

Comment: I'm curious why the downvote myself, because this looks like a potential solution.

Comment: This solution is fine